# mkfs.xfs: libxfs_device_zero write failed: Input/output error

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

I can't find a way to create a filesystem on one of my disks.

first i'm geting the following output:

```
[root@~]# mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1
mkfs.xfs: /dev/sdb1 appears to contain a partition table (dos).
mkfs.xfs: Use the -f option to force overwrite.
```

after using -F flag:

```
[root@~]# mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sdb1
meta-data=/dev/sdb1              isize=256    agcount=32, agsize=22892696 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=732566272, imaxpct=5
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=357698, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
**mkfs.xfs: libxfs_device_zero write failed: Input/output error**
```

/dev/sdb:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary
```

Linux:

```
Centos 6.3 Linux 1 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

what i've tried so far:
recreating partition with **parted rm 1**

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary

Comment: Version of Linux and distribution?

Comment: Centos 6.3 Linux 1 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

```
mkfs.xfs: libxfs_device_zero write failed: Input/output error
```

The message is very clear: it's a hardware problem. If it's a simple SATA or SAS drive, check connections, look dmesg for driver error messages. You could also give badblocks a try; my guess is that the disk is  failing and needs to be replaced, plain and simple.